# Using JSON file to create html page with list of neighborhoods using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am still an amateur when it comes to javascript but I have a JSON file that consists of an array of objects. Each object has two properties, a borough, and mappings. Mappings also has two properties, macro and neighborhoods. Macro is kind of like a larger neighborhood.

I need to display a list of boroughs along with their neighborhoods in a way that shows the hierarchy.

Fit macro neighborhoods into that hierarchy, but only list a macro neighborhood within the borough’s listing if it’s not the same as the borough. Also, the boroughs and macro neighborhoods should be ordered ascending by weight.

I have used the JSON formatter to turn the JSON file into a series of objects but I do not know how to reference it through html/javascript to create two  (one with the list of the neighborhoods and the other with the borough. Can anyone help?

EXAMPLE of file:

```
"data":[  
  {  
     "borough":{  
        "name":"Manhattan",
        "id":18,
        "weight":1
     },
     "mappings":[  
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"Below 14th St",
              "id":19,
              "weight":1
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":20,
                 "name":"Battery Park City"
              },
              {  
                 "id":21,
                 "name":"Civic Center"
              },
              {  
                 "id":22,
                 "name":"East Village"
              },
              {  
                 "id":23,
                 "name":"Financial District"
              },
              {  
                 "id":24,
                 "name":"Greenwich Village"
              },
              {  
                 "id":25,
                 "name":"Little Italy"
              },
              {  
                 "id":26,
                 "name":"Lower East Side"
              },
              {  
                 "id":27,
                 "name":"NoHo"
              },
              {  
                 "id":28,
                 "name":"Nolita"
              },
              {  
                 "id":29,
                 "name":"SoHo"
              },
              {  
                 "id":30,
                 "name":"TriBeCa"
              },
              {  
                 "id":31,
                 "name":"Union Square"
              },
              {  
                 "id":32,
                 "name":"West Village"
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"14th to 59th St",
              "id":33,
              "weight":2
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":34,
                 "name":"Flatiron"
              },
              {  
                 "id":35,
                 "name":"Gramercy"
              },
              {  
                 "id":36,
                 "name":"Kips Bay"
              },
              {  
                 "id":37,
                 "name":"Koreatown"
              },
              {  
                 "id":38,
                 "name":"Midtown East"
              },
              {  
                 "id":39,
                 "name":"Murray Hill"
              },
              {  
                 "id":41,
                 "name":"Chelsea"
              },
              {  
                 "id":42,
                 "name":"Hell's Kitchen"
              },
              {  
                 "id":43,
                 "name":"Midtown West"
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"Upper East",
              "id":44,
              "weight":3
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":45,
                 "name":"East Harlem"
              },
              {  
                 "id":46,
                 "name":"Roosevelt Island"
              },
              {  
                 "id":47,
                 "name":"Upper East Side"
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"Upper West",
              "id":48,
              "weight":4
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":49,
                 "name":"Central Park"
              },
              {  
                 "id":50,
                 "name":"Upper West Side"
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"Above 125th St",
              "id":51,
              "weight":5
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":52,
                 "name":"Harlem"
              },
              {  
                 "id":53,
                 "name":"Inwood"
              },
              {  
                 "id":54,
                 "name":"Washington Heights"
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "borough":{  
        "name":"Brooklyn",
        "id":55,
        "weight":2
     },
     "mappings":[  
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"Brooklyn Heights",
              "id":307,
              "weight":1
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":65,
                 "name":"Brooklyn Heights"
              },
              {  
                 "id":77,
                 "name":"DUMBO"
              },
              {  
                 "id":79,
                 "name":"Downtown Brooklyn"
              },
              {  
                 "id":117,
                 "name":"Vinegar Hill"
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "macro":{  
              "name":"BoCoCa",
              "id":306,
              "weight":2
           },
           "neighborhoods":[  
              {  
                 "id":62,
                 "name":"Boerum Hill"
              },
              {  
                 "id":69,
                 "name":"Carroll Gardens"
              },
              {  
                 "id":72,
                 "name":"Cobble Hill"
              },
              {  
                 "id":73,
                 "name":"Columbia Street Waterfront District"
              },
              {  
                 "id":108,
                 "name":"Red Hook"
              }
           ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one....

```
<select id="borough_list" name="borough_list">
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>
<select id="neighborhoods_list" name="neighborhoods_list">
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>

var obj = [
  {"borough":{"name":"Manhattan","id":18,"weight":1},
    "mappings":[  
      {"macro":{"name":"Below 14th St","id":19,"weight":1},
        "neighborhoods":[{"id":20,"name":"Battery Park City"},{"id":21,"name":"Civic Center"},{"id":22,"name":"East Village"},{"id":23,"name":"Financial District"},{"id":24,"name":"Greenwich Village"},{"id":25,"name":"Little Italy"},{"id":26,"name":"Lower East Side"},{"id":27,"name":"NoHo"},{"id":28,"name":"Nolita"},{"id":29,"name":"SoHo"},{"id":30,"name":"TriBeCa"},{"id":31,"name":"Union Square"},{"id":32,"name":"West Village"}]
      },
      {"macro":{"name":"14th to 59th St","id":33,"weight":2},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":34,"name":"Flatiron"},{"id":35,"name":"Gramercy"},{"id":36,"name":"Kips Bay"},{"id":37,"name":"Koreatown"},{"id":38,"name":"Midtown East"},{"id":39,"name":"Murray Hill"},{"id":41,"name":"Chelsea"},{"id":42,"name":"Hell's Kitchen"},{"id":43,"name":"Midtown West"}]
      },
      {"macro":{"name":"Upper East","id":44,"weight":3},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":45,"name":"East Harlem"},{"id":46,"name":"Roosevelt Island"},{"id":47,"name":"Upper East Side"}]
      },
      {"macro":{"name":"Upper West","id":48,"weight":4},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":49,"name":"Central Park"},{"id":50,"name":"Upper West Side"}]
      },
      {"macro":{"name":"Above 125th St","id":51,"weight":5},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":52,"name":"Harlem"},{"id":53,"name":"Inwood"},{"id":54,"name":"Washington Heights"}]
      }
    ]
  },
  {"borough":{"name":"Brooklyn","id":55,"weight":2},
    "mappings":[  
      {"macro":{"name":"Brooklyn Heights","id":307,"weight":1},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":65,"name":"Brooklyn Heights"},{"id":77,"name":"DUMBO"},{"id":79,"name":"Downtown Brooklyn"},{"id":117,"name":"Vinegar Hill"}]
      },
      {"macro":{"name":"BoCoCa","id":306,"weight":2},
    "neighborhoods":[{"id":62,"name":"Boerum Hill"},{"id":69,"name":"Carroll Gardens"},{"id":72,"name":"Cobble Hill"},{"id":73,"name":"Columbia Street Waterfront District"},{"id":108,"name":"Red Hook"}]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var borough = [];
var result_borough = [];
var mappings = [];
var neighborhoods = [];
var neighborhoods_list = [];
var result_neighborhoods = [];
obj.forEach(function(entry) {
    borough = entry.borough;
    mappings = entry.mappings;
    result_borough.push(borough);
    mappings.forEach(function(neighborhoods_list_entry) {
        neighborhoods_list = neighborhoods_list_entry.neighborhoods;
        neighborhoods_list.forEach(function(neighborhoods_entry) {
            result_neighborhoods.push(neighborhoods_entry);
        });
    });
});
console.log(result_borough);
console.log(result_neighborhoods);

result_borough.forEach(function(result_borough) {
    var select = document.getElementById("borough_list");
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = result_borough;
    opt.innerHTML = result_borough;
    select.appendChild(opt);
});

result_neighborhoods.forEach(function(result_neighborhoods) {
    var select = document.getElementById("neighborhoods_list");
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = result_neighborhoods;
    opt.innerHTML = result_neighborhoods;
    select.appendChild(opt);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I see that you grouped them was this done manually or did you use a formatter? Also, how do I get this to display as a list on HTML? I can see the listing in the console but I can't see it on the html page. Sorry I am still a newb with this stuff and it is a coding challenge.

Comment: Yes, I have done it manually.
Do you want these two lists as drop down in html ?

Comment: yes I would like it to look like two boxes: Box on the left Borough with list of neighborhoods and box on right the boroughs (Manhattan, Brooklyn, Queens, Bronx, Staten Island, New Jersey,Long Island)

Comment: I have updated the code and please find two drop down boxes above these scripts..
These code blocks works under html page...
<body> tag use these drop down box code.
<script> tag use rest of it...
https://jsfiddle.net/s052e9ds/

Comment: hmm I don't see anything appearing in the dropdown. I just see ("object ; object)

Comment: Yea I just used it and I still don't see it. Would you mind joining me on JSFiddle? I understand if you can't but if you can you'd be saving my life!

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qqbq5QPecl

Comment: You can simply click my link..
You dont need registration in jsfiddle...

Click this - https://jsfiddle.net/s052e9ds/1/

Comment: Ok I see it now. If I want the lists two be two divs, how do I reference them in the js file? I want it to look like this:

Comment: Look like what? Can you please share any design of that ?

Comment: Ok I see it now! If I would like the lists two be 2 <div>s, how do I reference them in the js file? I would ultimately like it to output like this: https://i.imgur.com/xRktKUt.png

Comment: Okay, Let me change it but do you need it with only javascript ?
Can i use php instead of js ?

Comment: I can only use javascript. Thank you so much for your help by the way!